# Inflating data and showing view takes long time

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using fragemnts in my application. the fragment contains some detailed information about the object I fetched form web.so the layout has many items and I need to inflate all of them for setting the data. I use `asynchtask` for loading data from the web and then make main fragment of the view visible. this is the code of my fragment's `oncreate` method:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_app_detail,
                container, false);

        final LayoutInflater inflaterFinal = inflater;

        // Rating View --------------------------------------
        final LinearLayout diagramContainers = (LinearLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.lyt_app_details_rating_container_diagrams);

        diagramContainers.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    // initialize helper variables------------
                    int width_fiveStartRateBar = 0;

                    int maxRateCount = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        maxRateCount = Math.max(maxRateCount,
                                app.getRateCounts()[i]);
                    }

                    int width_rateCountTxt = 0;
                    // initialize layout objects--------------
                    for (int j = 4; j >= 0; j--) {
                        LinearLayout diagramLyt = (LinearLayout) inflaterFinal
                                .inflate(
                                        R.layout.lyt_app_details_rating_diagram,
                                        null, false);

                        // star rate bar
                        RatingBar starRateBar = (RatingBar) diagramLyt
                                .findViewById(R.id.lyt_app_details_rating_diagram_rb_starbar);
                        starRateBar.setNumStars(j + 1);
                        starRateBar.setRating(j + 1);
                        starRateBar.measure(0, 0);
                        if (j == 4)
                            width_fiveStartRateBar = starRateBar
                                    .getMeasuredWidth();
                        else {
                            int p = width_fiveStartRateBar
                                    - starRateBar.getMeasuredWidth();
                            diagramLyt.setPadding(p, 0, 0, 0);
                        }

                        // rate Count txt
                        TextView rateCountTxt = (TextView) diagramLyt
                                .findViewById(R.id.lyt_app_details_rating_digram_txt_count);
                        rateCountTxt.setText(String.valueOf(app
                                .getRateCounts()[j]));
                        rateCountTxt.measure(0, 0);
                        width_rateCountTxt = rateCountTxt
                                .getMeasuredWidth();

                        // color bar
                        int totalWidth_colorBar = diagramContainers
                                .getWidth()
                                - (width_fiveStartRateBar + dpToPixel(5)
                                        + dpToPixel(5) + width_rateCountTxt);
                        float barWith = (totalWidth_colorBar * app
                                .getRateCounts()[j]) / maxRateCount;
                        LinearLayout bar = (LinearLayout) diagramLyt
                                .findViewById(R.id.lyt_app_details_rating_diagram_linear_colorbar);
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                (int) barWith, dpToPixel(12));
                        lp.setMargins(dpToPixel(5), 0, dpToPixel(5), 0);
                        bar.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        if (j == 4)
                            bar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_colorbar_five);
                        else if (j == 3)
                            bar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_colorbar_four);
                        else if (j == 2)
                            bar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_colorbar_three);
                        else if (j == 1)
                            bar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_colorbar_two);
                        else
                            bar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_colorbar_one);

                        diagramContainers.addView(diagramLyt);
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        // Thumb-nail Images Gallery ------------------------
        LinearLayout gallery = (LinearLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.gallery1);

        //gallery.post(new Runnable() {

        //  @Override
        //  public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < app.getThumbShotsLink().size(); i++) {

                    // get URL
                    final String tURL = app.getThumbShotsLink().get(i);
                    final String rURL = app.getScreenShotsLinks().get(i);

                    // create image view
                    ImageView v = new ImageView(getActivity());

                    // add layout parameters
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            dpToPixel(115), dpToPixel(175));
                    lp.setMargins(0, 0, dpToPixel(3), 0);
                    v.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    // set image
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                        v.setImageResource(R.color.light_green);
                    else
                        v.setImageResource(R.color.dark_green);

                    // listen to click
                    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO: OPEN FULL SCREEN IMAGE PAGE
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tURL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                    // add to view
                    gallery.addView(v);
                }
        //  }
        //});



        // Similar Apps -----------------------------------
        LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.app_details_llyt_similars);
        GridView similarGrid = (GridView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.lyt_app_similar_grid);
        similarGrid.setAdapter(new AppGridAdapter(app.getSimilarApps(),
                getActivity()));

        // Developer Apps ----------------------------------
        View v2 = (View) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.app_details_llyt_developer_apps);
        GridView developerGrid = (GridView) v2
                .findViewById(R.id.lyt_app_similar_grid);
        developerGrid.setAdapter(new AppGridAdapter(app.getDeveloperApps(),
                getActivity()));

        return rootView;
    }
```

the problem is that it takes about 5 sec that application load the layout and set the data to it. I am looking for a way that how can I inflate the layout and set the data to them so that app do not lock for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to fully understand your code.
What are you trying to do with ths following line ?

```
diagramContainers.post(new Runnable() { ...
```

This call won't create a new thread to execute the job in background. It will only be executed after the end of onCreate(). Maibe some of your performance issues comes from that.

The way you create new views to add them to a parent layout also seem wrong to me. You should never have to create so many views programaticaly. You should be using a ViewGroup/Adapter pattern (cf [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) link). Adapters will manage view internaly and reuse views if necessary. This could improve your performances drastically.

EDIT :

You can use multiple listview. You could have on for each type of item (one for diagrams, onefor thumbnails etc...).
Anyway it seem like in your diagramContainers section, you are always inflating the same number of views. In that case why not create these view in the xml. That would inprove you performances.

Try posting your R.layout.fragment_app_detail layout so that I can understand better what you are doing.

Comment: I use grid view and list view for when my activity items are same. in this page I have about 7-8 different items in my activity. some of them it self are scrollview and a grid view. I this it is not a good idea to use a grid view or list view as the root of this activity

Comment: also I use the line you refereed exactly for what you said. I needed the width of 'diagramContainer' for creating my view so used this line for sending some of calculation for when the width was available. I also think it is the problem and commented it but still problem alive.